# Active High and Low in Combinational Logic Analysis

Tags: digital-logic

I'm working through Joseph Cavanagh's *Digital Design and Verilog HDL Fundamentals*. In chapter 3, he discusses using (+) and (-) in front of bits to indicate active high and active low signals, i.e.

[image]

I understand the concept of active low, where a logical 0 is a TRUE.  And I think I understand what he's saying for figure (a), the equation is -z1 = (x1x2), and for (b), in order to get -z1, the active low signal, the equation is (x1x2').  What I want to make sure I understand are the semantics, for lack of a better term, of figure (b).  x1 is active high, x2, because of the (-) is active low, so in order to drive z1 low (i.e., -z1), x2 has to be negated so that -x2 becomes x2 (i.e, x2').

I was interpreting figure (b) as NAND(1, 0) = z1, and what we want is NAND(1, 0') = -z1, but the discussion of active high and active low was confusing me.  I think what I would like is confirmation my interpretation of figures (a) and (b) are correct.  Or that I am over analysing this.

Comment: So far as I know, this notation (\$-x_1\$ to indicate logical negation of \$x_1\$) is not common outside of that particular book. So you'll have to look to that book to find out the details of how it is interpreted.

Comment: IMHO you've overanalyzing, and the book author did moreso.  The behavior of gates is what it is, reflecting actual levels.  "Active High" vs "Active Low" relates to how *meaning* is assigned to those levels, eg which one enables the cookie dispenser.  But it does not change how they are treated in the sense of combinatorial logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For figure (a):

```
           -z1 = x1 & x2
            z1 = (x1 & x2)' (NAND operation)
```

For figure (b):

```
          -z1 = x1 & x2' 
        => z1 = (x1 & x2')' (Taking complement on both sides)
```

Here & stands for the and operation.

> so in order to drive z1 low (i.e., -z1), x2 has to be negated

It is not correct to say an input is negated, instead, we say a LOW on x2 and a HIGH on x1, produces a LOW on z1.

So z1 = x1 NAND x2' in the case of figure (b).